# Error Installing Sun JDK 6

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, jdk6

I am trying to install the SUN JDK 6 on my VM running Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit Desktop.

"sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk" won't work because Sun JDK 6 is no longer available via apt-get since the Oracle acquisition.

So I went to the Oracle website and downloaded jdk-6u26-linux-x64.bin
Then ran the following commands

```
  sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm ; cd /usr/lib/jvm
  sudo cp ~/Downloads/jdk-6u26-linux-x64.bin .
  sudo chmod +x jdk-6u26-linux-x64.bin
  sudo ./jdk-6u26-linux-x64.bin
```

but I the install fails at extraction. Here it is:
[image]

I do need to have the specific version of Ubuntu and the Java JSK for what I am doing and I am still kind of new to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

you can try in terminal (ctrl + alt + F1 ) ;
 apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Comment: nope didn't work, it says the package is not available. Note my first comment. I don't think apt-get will work for installing Java 6 sdk

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the file download has not failed and follow this guide
http://rafacompnotes.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/hello-world/